# Соединить FormData с serialize

Tags: jquery, ajax, formdata

Как можно связать data с forma, что бы в обработчик пришло все как надо?

```
var data = new FormData();
var forma = $("#my_form").serialize();

$.each($("#idea_files")[0].files, function(i, file) {
    data.append("files[]", file);
});

$.ajax({
    url: $url,
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
        console.log('ОШИБКА: ' + textStatus );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var data = new FormData($("#my_form")[0]);
// далее - по тексту
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: Спасибо мастер. Я в английском не очень, поэтому не знал где искать.

Comment: @Владимир Просто сделайте поиск на странице по ссылке на "new FormData". Рад помочь. Успехов.